# Multiple Transactions in a Stored procedures MySql

Tags: mysql, sql

Code structure like

```
    Procedure (sp1)
        start transaction 
          select ....    
          insert ...    
          CALL sp2    
        END Transaction
   end procedure
```

The wire frame is like that. In that my doubt is

1.sp2 is called within the sp1 under transaction. will the same transaction
is applicable for sp2 or not ?

2.secondly if i need a different transaction level in sp2 can i include transaction in 
sp2 separetly or not along with transaction in sp1 also?

I am new to DataBase. Help me in figuring out this..

Thanks in advance..

Comment: can I use autocommit=0 insted of using start transaction in nested sp

Answer (score 1):

You can't directly nest transactions in MySQL, but sp2 would run just fine inside sp1's transaction, as long as sp2 doesn't also try to `START TRANSACTION`, because starting a transaction while already inside a transaction implicitly commits the first transaction, making a rollback impossible for the original transaction.

A better and safer approach is for the invoker of the procedure to be in charge of the transaction, and the procedure to wrap itself in a savepoint.  Then the procedure can rollback to the savepoint that it created, if needed, to handle errors -- and savepoints can be nested.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/savepoint.html

Comment: Shall I use autocommit=0 insted of using start transaction in nested sp @Michael - sqlbot

Comment: @selvakumar I don't believe that will accomplish anything.

Comment: I'm doing exactly this, however, the transaction doesn't work inside the inner procedure. I am not starting a transaction in the inner procedure, but I'm wrapping multiple calls to procedures inside a single transaction. The outer procedure rollbacks depending on a certain out param of the inner, but it doesn't actually rollback the changes made by the inner procedure.